# why can I not instantiate a class by doing "myVector[i].data()", where myVector[i].data() is a string?

Tags: c++, string, class, instantiation

I am using a code that someone else wrote for calculating chemical reactions.  The user must specify many values for a calculation and this can lead to mistakes.  I am trying to automate/simply this process.

I can instantiate a class by doing (for example):

```
Algorithm<double>  chlorine;
```

I would like to do multiple instantiations--for example, chlorine, hydrogen, and oxygen.  I don't understand why I get a segmentation fault when I put "chlorine," "hydrogen," and "oxygen" as elements in a vector of strings called "chemicalElements"and then do:

```
for (i = 0; i < chemicalElements.size(); i++) 
{   
    Algorithm<double> chemicalElements[i].data();   
}
```

Am I missing something simple here?  When I write:

```
Algorithm<double>  chlorine;
```

"chlorine" is just a string, right?  So why would it not work to add "chlorine" from an element in a vector of strings?

Comment: Please get a text book on C++ and start with something simpler. It is not productive to ask about the very basics of a language on Stack OVerflow when there are far better and more suitable resources for learning out there.

Comment: I have spent the past two weeks trying to figure this out.  I don't use C++ that often because I'm a chemist.  If it is so simple, it would be great to be pointed in the right direction.

Comment: If `chemicalElements[i].data();` is a string then you just cannot use the contents of that string as a name for a variable (the `chlorine` in your example is not a string but a name of an object of type `Algorithm<double>`).

Comment: @user616199: The direction you're looking for is "declaring variables". Seriously, *any* programming tutorial will cover this.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I get that you're a lot smarter than me.  Congratulations.  I have pored over every C++ book I can get my hands on and have not managed to make the connection on this particular issue, which is why I'm asking for advice here.  I have read about declaration.  Coding is not the focus of what I do and in order to make any progress, I sometimes need help.  If you don't want to participate in this question, that is fine with me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`chlorine` is *not* a string in your example code, it's an identifier for a variable (of type `Algorithm<double>`).

Variables must be given *compile-time* identifiers; that means the identifier must be specified when the compiler is traversing your code. The result of `chemicalElements[i].data()` is unknown until *runtime*.

C++ doesn't have any facility for creating variable names at runtime, so you cannot do what you are *directly* asking. However, it sounds like what you really need is a collection of algorithm objects, one for each of your elements. To create an *array* of algorithm objects, you can do:

```
Algorithm<double> algorithms[15];
```

This creates 15 distinct algorithm objects, which you can map to your elements however you like. You can of course choose a different number than 15, so long as that number is a compile-time constant value.

You may also be interested in learning about [`std::vector<T>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), a type that allows you to create dynamically-resizing arrays, or [`std::map<K,V>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) which allows you to create an associative mapping between a key value (a string, such as "chlorine," and a value, such as the associated algorithm).

To use the latter, you can do something like this:

```
std::map<std::string, Algorithm<double>> algorithms;
algorithms["chlorine"] = Algorithm<double>();
algorithms["argon"] = Algorithm<double>();
```

and then later:

```
auto results = algorithms["chlorine"].data();
```

(You should of course peruse the linked documentation on the above types, since I am omitting some error handling for brevity.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patience.  Your explanation about compile- and runtime really helps me understand what is going on.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithm chlorine , means that
You've instantiated an "Algorithm" object named "chlorine"

to make array of "Algorithm"
you code it like:

```
Algorithm<double> chemicalElements[Const_num];
```

and to pass through each one of its items you call the array's name + it's index like:

```
chemicalElements[0 or 1 or 2 or ... etc].data();
```

So it would be like

```
for (i = 0; i < Const_num i++) 
{   
    chemicalElements[i].data();   
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In this statement

```
Algorithm<double>  chlorine;
```

chlorine is not a string. It is an identificator that names an object of type `Algorithm<double>`.

This construction

```
Algorithm<double> chemicalElements[i].data();
```

has no syntaxical sense in C++ and the compiler shall issue an error.